# conditional probability that 5 red balls were placed in the bowl at random

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Place five similar balls (each either red or blue) in a bowl at random as follows:  A coin is flipped 5 independent times ad a red ball is placed in the bowl for each head and a blue ball for each tail. The bowl is then taken and two balls are selected at random without replacement. Given that each of those two balls is red, compute the conditional probability that 5 red balls were placed in the bowl at random. .Solution: let x= number of heads and y=number of tails. Thus., each distribution has Binomial with n=5 and p=0.5. Please help. I am stuck with this.

Comment: This is a trick question. The chance that the remaining 3 balls are red is independent of the colors of the balls you already chose.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the probability that all five were heads and the two selected were red is $1/32$. Without loss of generality, assume the two selected at random were the first two put in (the probability that we selected any given two balls is the same as selecting any other two). The probability that these both were red is $1/4$. Thus the conditional probability is $(1/32)/(1/4)=1/8$.

More intuitively, we can say that the outcome of the other 3 was independent of the 2 selected as mentioned in the comments. Thus
$$P(\mbox{other 3 were all red}|\mbox{ones we selected were both red})= P(\mbox{other 3 were all red})=1/8$$

Comment: I think you are wrong in assuming that the first $2$ balls placed in the bowl are also the the first $2$ balls selected from the bowl.

Comment: @barakmanos the probability is 1/4 given any two ordered selections of balls. Each ordered selection has probability $1/20$ and there are 20 possible ordered selections. Therefore the total probability is 1/4. This can be interpreted as saying it doesn't matter which two were selected.

Comment: I don't understand this comment, and in addition, it looks different from the answer.

Comment: @barakmanos sent it too early, please see edit.

Comment: I solve this using *conditional probability* formula, and I get $\frac{1}{26}$ ($26$ combinations of $2$ or more red balls, out of which - $1$ combination of $5$ red balls).

Comment: @barakmanos post your answer then.

Comment: Trying to figure out what's wrong with my answer (if anything) before I post it... Second thought, there you go. Please comment if you see the problem.

Comment: @barakmanos that's if we know that at least two balls are red. We know however that two particular balls are red.

Comment: "The bowl is then taken and two balls are selected at random without replacement. Given that each of those two balls is red..." - doesn't that mean that at least $2$ balls are red?

Comment: @barakmanos the probability that the other 3 balls are red is independent of the probability that the two we selected are red.

Comment: Right. This claim I agree with. But I can't see how it refutes my claim above it (and obviously one of them is wrong, because they yield different results).

Comment: @barakmanos Similarly, the probability that the other 3 balls were in any combination is independent of the probability of the two we selected being red. Therefore the probability that the two we selected are red is $1/4$. This is somewhat similar to Monty hall...Knowing that at least two balls are red is different from knowing a particular two balls are red.

Comment: One difference is, in order to pick two balls from the bowl and observe that they are both red, first there had to be at least two red balls in the bowl _and then_ you had to pick two balls without picking any of the blue ones. Even with four red balls in the bowl you have only a $60$% chance to pick two red balls at random; for two or three red balls in the bowl your chance of picking two red balls is much worse. So the events described are very different from "there are at least two red balls".